# Postgres Trigrams and ordering verly slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to build up a fuzzy search against multiple columns with weightings for each column's distance from the corresponding search term.

I have the following query -

```
select sf_id 
from (
  select * 
  from (
     select sf_id , 
            (1.0 - cast(coalesce(mailingcity, '') <->> 'san ant' as float)) * 3.0  as score  
     from contacts 
     order by score desc 
     limit 1000
  ) as mailingcity

  union

  select * 
  from (
    select sf_id, 
           (1.0 - cast(coalesce(lastname, '') <->> 'anders' as float)) * 5.0 as score  
    from contacts 
    order by score 
    desc limit 1000
  ) as lastname
) 
as agg 
group by sf_id 
order by sum(score) desc
```

with indexes such as the following -

```
create index contact_lastname_trgrm_idx on contacts using gin (lastname gin_trgm_ops)
```

on the columns used to match on.

We have ~ 500,000 records in the table and the query is taking over three seconds.

I also have expression indexes on the coalesce function

Is there any way to speed this up?

Result of EXPLAIN -

```
Sort  (cost=212791.05..212791.55 rows=200 width=154) (actual time=3165.154..3165.247 rows=2000 loops=1)
  Sort Key: (sum(((('1'::double precision - (((COALESCE(contacts.mailingcity, ''::character varying))::text <->> 'san ant'::text))::double precision) * '3'::double precision)))) DESC
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 205kB
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=212766.41..212783.41 rows=200 width=154) (actual time=3163.855..3164.621 rows=2000 loops=1)
        Group Key: contacts.sf_id
        ->  Sort  (cost=212766.41..212771.41 rows=2000 width=154) (actual time=3163.847..3163.966 rows=2000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: contacts.sf_id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 205kB
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=212616.75..212636.75 rows=2000 width=154) (actual time=3155.719..3156.055 rows=2000 loops=1)
                    Group Key: contacts.sf_id, ((('1'::double precision - (((COALESCE(contacts.mailingcity, ''::character varying))::text <->> 'san ant'::text))::double precision) * '3'::double precision))
                    ->  Append  (cost=106166.70..212606.75 rows=2000 width=154) (actual time=1629.241..3154.841 rows=2000 loops=1)
                          ->  Limit  (cost=106166.70..106283.37 rows=1000 width=27) (actual time=1629.241..1629.798 rows=1000 loops=1)
                                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=106166.70..154807.03 rows=416888 width=27) (actual time=1629.239..1629.730 rows=1000 loops=1)
                                      Workers Planned: 2
                                      Workers Launched: 2
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=105166.68..105687.79 rows=208444 width=27) (actual time=1589.059..1589.232 rows=1021 loops=3)
                                            Sort Key: ((('1'::double precision - (((COALESCE(contacts.mailingcity, ''::character varying))::text <->> 'san ant'::text))::double precision) * '3'::double precision)) DESC
                                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7256kB
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on contacts  (cost=0.00..81763.88 rows=208444 width=27) (actual time=0.145..1405.681 rows=166755 loops=3)
                          ->  Limit  (cost=106166.70..106283.37 rows=1000 width=27) (actual time=1524.305..1524.912 rows=1000 loops=1)
                                ->  Gather Merge  (cost=106166.70..154807.03 rows=416888 width=27) (actual time=1524.304..1524.842 rows=1000 loops=1)
                                      Workers Planned: 2
                                      Workers Launched: 2
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=105166.68..105687.79 rows=208444 width=27) (actual time=1455.159..1455.386 rows=1016 loops=3)
                                            Sort Key: ((('1'::double precision - (((COALESCE(contacts_1.lastname, ''::character varying))::text <->> 'anders'::text))::double precision) * '5'::double precision)) DESC
                                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7280kB
                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on contacts contacts_1  (cost=0.00..81763.88 rows=208444 width=27) (actual time=0.373..1290.368 rows=166755 loops=3)
Planning time: 0.855 ms
Execution time: 3218.589 ms
```

As per the advice from @a_horse_with_no_name below, the following query now runs at ~250ms

```
select sf_id from (select * from (
select sf_id , 
(1.0 - cast(coalesce(mailingcity, '') <->> 'san ant' as float)) * 3.0 
as score  
from contacts 
    where mailingcity % 'san ant' 
    order by score desc limit 1000) as mailingcity
union all
select * from (
select sf_id, 
(1.0 - cast(coalesce(lastname, '') <->> 'anders' as float)) * 5.0 as score  
from contacts 
    where lastname % 'anders'
    order by score desc limit 1000) as lastname) 
as agg group by sf_id order by sum(score) desc
```

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output and format the query so that it is readable.

Comment: The first optimization is to use `union all` instead of `union`

Comment: And index is used to quickly find the rows to be evaluated - typically specified by a `where` clause. Your individual queries are requesting **all** rows which then need to be sorted and then most of that is discarded then. If at all an index on the **complete** expression and the `sf_id` might help

Comment: I have updated the EXPLAIN to text as per a_horse_with_no_name's request

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks!!
With your advice the following query is down to 250 MS!!!

select sf_id from (select * from (
select sf_id , 
(1.0 - cast(coalesce(mailingcity, '') <->> 'san ant' as float)) * 3.0 
as score  
from contacts 
 where mailingcity % 'san ant' 
 order by score desc limit 1000) as mailingcity
union all
select * from (
select sf_id, 
(1.0 - cast(coalesce(lastname, '') <->> 'anders' as float)) * 5.0 as score  
from contacts 
 where lastname % 'anders'
 order by score desc limit 1000) as lastname) 
as agg group by sf_id order by sum(score) desc